# Close Vaadin notification when click outside of the message box

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

setDelayMSec( -1 ) means that the message is displayed until the user clicks on the message box. Can I close to message box when user clicks anywhere outside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add a tag that uses the entire screen, with this:

```
public void createAndShowNotification(String caption, String description, Notification.Type type) {
    description += "<span style=\"position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%\"></span>";
    Notification notif = new Notification(caption, description, type, true);
    notif.setDelayMsec(-1);
    notif.show(Page.getCurrent());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, when you use setDelayMSec(-1) then you have to click in the message box to close it.

If the user should be able to close it by clicking anywhere outside the box, you have to set a positive number.
Of course you can set a very high number, so that it does (almost) not autocloses...

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.notifications.html

Comment: Thanks, but the setDelayMSec() allows setting the time for how long the notification is displayed in milliseconds, does not depend on cliks!

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.
As soon as we have a positive delay, then either a click inside or the timeout closes the notification. The Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE is probabaly closest to what you wish to do. It closes on mouse move. Otherwise you have to fill a RFE